# How to solve error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting this error , how to solve this relation error

[image]

i have a model called `property.rb`

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :rm
    belongs_to :category
end
```

also i have category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rms,dependent: :destroy
    has_many :properties,dependent: :destroy
end
```

my RM(relationship Manager) model is

```
class Rm < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :properties
end
```

in my controller i listing properties like this

```
class Rms::PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @properties = Property.all
  end
 def property_params
 params.require(:property).permit(:seller_name,:rm_id,:category_id,:property_type_id,:seller_email,:seller_phone,:property_name)
  end
end
```

in my view page 
i am listing the property added by RM in index.html.erb

```
    <% @properties.each do |property| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= property.seller_name %></td>
        <td><%= property.seller_email %></td>
        <td><%= property.seller_phone %></td>
        <td><%= property.category.name %></td>
        <td><%= property.property_name %></td>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `category` always associated with `property`.

In Property model add:

```
validates :category, presence: true
```

If your products not necessarily always have category, you can use safe navigation ( which is almost always an ugly solution):

```
product.category.try(:name) # Ruby <  2.3.x
product.category&.name      # Ruby >= 2.3.x
```

Answer (score 2):

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

It is because one of the `property` don't have a `category` associated to it. The immediate fix would be to use [**`try`**](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object%3Atry) method.

```
<%= property.category.try(:name) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It occurs because the `property` doesn't have a `category` associated with it.
So

```
<td><%= property.category.name %></td>
```

throws the error

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

since `name` is not present for a nil class which in this case is `category`
You can use a gem named `andand` to handle such cases.
After installing the gem simply rewrite the code as:

```
<td><%= property.andand.category.name %></td>
```

Comment: did you install the gem andand ?

Comment: Please list andand in your Gemfile and run bundle install

Comment: Using try is not "pretty". http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/06/28/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try/

Comment: will it create any problem in code if i tried with try?

Comment: No it will not create a problem. It is not a best coding practice. That's all. Using try will work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Might be the property doesn't have a category.Try Using:

```
<%= property.category.name rescue nil%>
```

Comment: will not be successful, since issue is the raised exception, not `nil`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - I have tried this code and it solves the issue as rescue is used to handle exceptions :)

Comment: I meant that this solution does not make a lot of sense cause it's rather a band-aid